# What Arguments are Used in Createblock() method Of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I am trying to create an simple form in magento Backend (Admin Side).. I want to display a button "Add New" on right side of it.
I have used the following code

`$this->loadLayout()
     ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace_mymodule'))
     ->renderLayout();`

But its not working... I don't know what exactly are the arguments that i need to pass in CreateBlock() method.. I have just  Can Anyone Help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createBlock($class_string)` method creates an instance of a block, much in the same way that `Mage::getModel($class_string)` and `Mage::helper($class_string)` create instances of models and helpers, respectively.

To create a simple form, you'll need to associate your block with a template, which you can do by calling the `->setTemplate($template_file)` method on your newly created block.  Other than that, we're going to need more information to help.